# Data not displaying in View from controller codelgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I am learning CodeIgniter; in my program I am trying to populate a dropdown from mysql database but I seemed to be doing something wrong.

Please find below what I tried:

**Model**

In my model I tried to use different select methods I found online but all failed so I stick with the below method and still failed.

```
 function getAllVendors()
    {
    $this->db->select('DISTINCT SUBSTRING(product_code,1,3) as vendor')
    ->order_by('vendor');
    $q = $this->db->get('tec_sale_items');
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function allVendors(){ 
    $this->data['vendors'] = $this->vendors_sales_model->getAllVendors();
 $this->page_construct('reports/vendors_sales_details', $this->data);
  }
```

**View**

```
 <select class="form-control">
   <option value="">All</option>
      <?php
       foreach($vendors as $ven)
          {
           echo '<option value="'.$ven['vendor'].'">'.$ven['vendor'].'</option>';
          }
      ?> 
</select>
```

Could someone please point me to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you might be forget to call view into your controller. Load view in the controller `$this->load->view("your view file name")` and pass the data you got from your database.

First make sure that you are getting proper data from model. And as I see your are using current object of class `$this->data['vendors']` so you have to use same in the code

```
<select class="form-control">

<option value="">All</option> <?php
   foreach($this->data['vendors'] as $ven)
         {
    echo '<option value="'.$ven['vendor'].'">'.$ven['vendor'].'</option>';
          }
   ?>
</select>
```

May be it's helpful .

And you should use ci4 it's 3rd version of ci and  it's no longer maintained. For better security and performance change php server 7.4 and above.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I actually used **$this->load->view('reports/vendors_sales_details',$this->data);** before settling with **$this->page_construct('reports/vendors_sales_details', $this->data);** but didn't work. I'll keep trying. Thanks again

Comment: i think the function you want is View() not $this->load->view(). and dont forget to return or echo the view. here is the example: echo view('reports/vendors_sales_details', $this->data);

Comment: No only ci4 uses view helper if you are using ci3 then you need to use view function of input class with current instance.

Comment: I believe it should be `$this->load->view(...)`. If it is loaded with ajax, same function have parameters to return it as a string..